# How do I compare the same value in multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, nested

I am working on a project that involves a nested array, and I need to sort 1 value from each array by size. (All arrays are in the same format e.g. [a,b,c,d]).
To make it clearer, how would I choose the bigger number out of an array like `time[60][x]` where x is the number of arrays (it is a very strange nest).

```js
const time = {
  15: [
    { language: 'english', raw: 105.6, acc: 93.94, wpm: 96, punctuation: false }
  ],
  30: [
    { language: 'english', raw: 66.4, wpm: 66.4, punctuation: false, difficulty: 'normal' }
  ],
  60: [
    { acc: 98.97, language: 'english', puncutation: false, wpm: 96, difficulty: 'normal' },
    { acc: 92.63, puncutation: false, language: 'english_10k', wpm: 59.19, raw: 60.99 }
  ]
};
```

As you can see, each array has a different number of arrays nested into it for example `time[60][2]` has 2 arrays in it.
This is the structure of the object. I need to find the greatest value out of the wpm column for each array.
Any and all help is greatly appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: "I need to find the greatest value out of the wpm column for each array". Do you mean the greatest wpm for each of the arrays under key "time"? If so what is your expected output to look like? Or do you mean the greatest wpm of the whole set returned as a number?

Comment: the greatest wpm of the set for each time period, e.g. 15 second test wpm is different to the 60 second wpm. Expected output would be the highest wpm for the selected time period (out of 15, 30 and 60 seconds) as a decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this might be what you need:

```js
const time = {
  15: [{wpm: 10}, {wpm: 15}, {wpm: 20}],
  30: [{wpm: 5}, {wpm: 10}, {wpm: 30},],
  60: [{wpm: 4}, {wpm: 12}, {wpm: 8},]
};

const results = {};

// iterate over the time object
for (let key in time) {
  results[key] = time[key].reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (item.wpm > acc) {
      return item.wpm;
    }
    
    return acc;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(results);
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/geuis/pen/VwaxWWY

Comment: Why are you insisting on linking to an external codepen as opposed to a stack snippet?  I edited your post to be a snippet and you reverted it.

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer, i'm struggling to understand this code, does it return a single value for the highest wpm?

Comment: @GirkovArpa yep, didn't know about snippets. Neat feature.

Comment: You have 35.7k reputation and you didn't know about snippets?  Glad to help though!

Comment: This is perfect, but i need a single val returned, for a single time period. Would i simply filter the array and its done?

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear from your question initially. But I've updated the answer to return just the largest wpm value.

Comment: Perfect, really appreciate all of the help and effort

Answer (score 0):

```js
Object
  .fromEntries(Object
    .entries(time)
    .map(([key, array]) => ([key, Math.max(...array.map(({ wpm }) => wpm))])));
```

Live example:

```js
const time = {
  15: [
    { language: 'english', raw: 105.6, acc: 93.94, wpm: 96, puncutation: false }
  ],
  30: [
    { language: 'english', raw: 66.4, wpm: 66.4, punctuation: false, difficulty: 'normal' }
  ],
  60: [
    { acc: 98.97, language: 'english', puncutation: false, wpm: 96, difficulty: 'normal' },
    { acc: 92.63, puncutation: false, language: 'english_10k', wpm: 59.19, raw: 60.99 }
  ]
};

const maxes = Object
  .fromEntries(Object
    .entries(time)
    .map(([key, array]) => ([key, Math.max(...array.map(({ wpm }) => wpm))])));

console.log(maxes);
```

To preserve the entire object so that you can then access its other properties besides `wpm`:

```js
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(time).map(([key, arr]) => ([key, arr.find(({ wpm }) => wpm == Math.max(...arr.map(({ wpm }) => wpm)))])));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect for what I needed

Comment: I would recommend against using code like this in production. One liners are very neat and cute, but can be hard to debug what is actually happening in the code. On top of that, this code is about 40% slower than the answer I gave below. https://jsbench.me/gykeypgb4b/1

Comment: @GirkovArpa if i wanted to select the raw from the same array that the highest wpm is in would i simply change 'wpm' to 'raw'? or would that not pull from the same array, and would just find the highest value of raw from each array?

Comment: Your hunch is correct regarding changing `wpm` to `raw` by the way.